# $ \forall x ( P(x) \lor Q(x)) \iff \forall x (P(x)) \lor \forall x (Q(x) ) $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

**(1)** $ \forall x ( P(x) \lor  Q(x))  \iff     \forall x (P(x)) \lor \forall x (Q(x) )     $, is this the same as writing $ \forall x ( P(x) \lor  Q(x))  \equiv     \forall x (P(x)) \lor \forall x (Q(x) $ ?

As the truth table for iff requires both sides to evaluate to true or both sides to evaluate to false, in order for the statement to be true?

**(2)** I cannot convince myself that the above iff statement is false, I tried this counter-example: Let the domain of discourse be {2}, P(x) = x is even, Q(x) = x is odd. Then wouldn't both sides of the iff statement evaluate to true, since P(x) is true, Q(x) is false, then $P(x) \lor Q(x)$ is true?. I am not exactly sure how th**e scope of the quantifier affects the truth values** of the predicates?

Would appreciate any help to clear this doubt, thanks!

Comment: They are not equivalent. Compare "Every number is (either Even or Odd)" with "(Every number is Even) or (Every number is Odd)"

Comment: But if you had $\land$ between the statements, then they are equivalent

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks. So, substituting in 2 to get the values of the predicates is the wrong way to do it? We should always interpret the statement in english first?

Comment: @Physor Sorry, do you mean $ \forall x (P(x) \land Q(x)) $ ?

Comment: yes, that what I mean

Comment: You have to search for an interpretation that **falsifies** the equivalence. Equivalence means that in **each** interpretation the two formulas have the same truth value: having found one that is so it is not enough.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, do you think they are not ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%E2%88%80x(P(x)%E2%88%A7Q(x))%20%E2%86%94%20(%E2%88%80xP(x))%E2%88%A7(%E2%88%80xQ(x))

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I think of them in way similar as in a previous question, you answered, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828752/forall-x-exists-y-px-wedge-qy-overset-iff-exists-y-forall

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, in your example you should have said, (every number is even *and* odd) is the same as ((every number is even) *and* (every number is odd)), there is no or

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA For the either or statement, it doesn't restrict x from making both predicates Q(x), P(x) true right? For example, Every fruit is (either sweet or sour), I could have a fruit that is sweet and sour, so the statement would be true. Every fruit is sweet is true. Every fruit is sour is also true. so the apply $ \lor $ would make this statement true as well? When would this statement be false?

Comment: @Physor But, the question uses $ \lor $

Comment: yes, I know that the question uses $\vee$, and I know that they are *Not* equivalent, but I said if it were $\land$ then they would be equivalent.

Comment: I was answering @user61239 for his question on my comment, sorry for the long train of comments

Comment: No wait, the either was a problem

Comment: @Physor Yup, that was what I was struggling with, what happens if I use an x that satisfies both predicates and not strictly satisfy one predicate (shown in the fruit example above)